# Windows CE On Laptop

Tags: windows, embedded, gps, windows-ce

I have old-ish laptop that comes with touch screen.

What I wanna do is buy GPS module for it and install basic windows ce on it.

Then use it as gps navigation with igo 8 for ce

Is that possible?

How would I exactly install windows ce to laptops hard drive and make it start igo 8 right away?

Comment: As far as I know, CE only runs on ARM CPUs, and I'm guessing your laptop is x86, so it's not going to happen.

Comment: @Randolph Potter - not true, read my answer.

Comment: @Wil - interesting. Voting you up.

Answer (score 8):

Windows CE is typically an embedded operating system and is not straight forward to get running on other hardware.

Windows CE is not a simple CD you can install from like the regular editions of Windows you can buy from a shop. It is designed to be a highly configurable*, customisable, very flexible operating system.

It has to be "built" for each target. If you have a MSDN subscription (I forget the level needed), you can download a disk called "Windows Embedded CE 6.0 R3 - DVD (English)" (It is under development tools, I can't quickly see a way to deeplink in). This contains a tool which is called "Platform Builder". I have not run this in many years, but I do not think it has changed.

Using platform builder, you can choose from MANY templates - from a ip phone, set top box, down to full desktop and completely customise many aspects of Windows CE. You will need to target the X86 CPU and most likely will need to find/acquire/build drivers for certain hardware such as the touch screen.

Once built, by default, it installs a trial key which allows the built image to run for a short while (I think 30 or 60 days... but that is off the top of my head). In order to buy a full licence, you need to go to a Windows Embedded Distributor - and for just one unit... you may have a little trouble.

Personally, You may be best off sticking Google Maps (if you have a 3g dongle/internet connection) or Microsoft Autoroute (I think it is) as it has a complete database built in - and is GPS compatible.

As for other aspects, on X86 hardware, it should be quite fast, but do not expect it to be as fast as on dedicated Windows CE devices - many of them are purpose built with flash memory, and BSP (Motherboards that are deeply linked to the OS) for maximum speed.

`*` You would be surprised how many set top boxes, GPSs and other high end electronic goods run it!

Good luck and it sounds interesting, so please let me know what route you end up going down!

Comment: ... After re-reading my answer, I am not 100% sure about licensing... I think I have that muddled up with Windows XP Embedded... I think technically you are only meant to use it for xx days, but it is not enforced... not entirely sure, everything else should still be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your are (easily) going to be able to install Windows CE on an old laptop.

If you are looking to use your laptop as a GPS navigation system check out the free [GPSDrive](http://www.gpsdrive.de/screenshots/index.shtml) app which runs on Linux, or alternatively Google Maps, at least on Chrome, will update its location continually based on wifi/cell phone towers, making it easy to turn a laptop into a poor man's navigation system.

You can also use free [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) application to connect to a GPS on your laptop and show a location continually updated. You could get the maps for free from OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1):

Yoiu should look into putting Android on the computer. There is an x86 port of Gingerbread (2.3) being developed.
http://www.android-x86.org/

Comment: Do you then get the Google Maps app for it?